# Failing to flash custom (Magisk-patched) boot.img to Samsung S20 FE (4G) with Heimdall

Tags: rom-flashing, bootloader, heimdall

I am attempting to flash a [Magisk](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk)-patched `boot.img` from Linux onto my unlocked SM-G780G. I have so far tried doing that using `fastboot flash ...` to which the device responded that it doesn't know the command.

The device is a Samsung Galaxy S20 FE (SM-G780G).

I then tried [Heimdall](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall) v1.4.2 (on Ubuntu 20.4) and got this:

```
$ sudo heimdall download-pit --output bla.pit --verbose --stdout-errors
Heimdall v1.4.2

Copyright (c) 2010-2017 Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
      Manufacturer: "Samsung"
           Product: "SM8250"

            length: 18
      device class: 2
               S/N: 0
           VID:PID: 04E8:685D
         bcdDevice: 0100
   iMan:iProd:iSer: 1:2:0
          nb confs: 1

interface[0].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 1
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 02.02.01
       endpoint[0].address: 82
           max packet size: 0010
          polling interval: 09

interface[1].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 2
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 0A.00.00
       endpoint[0].address: 01
           max packet size: 0400
          polling interval: 00
       endpoint[1].address: 81
           max packet size: 0400
          polling interval: 00
Claiming interface...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending bulk transfer.ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending bulk transfer. Retrying...
 Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending bulk transfer.ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending bulk transfer. Retrying...
 Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending bulk transfer.ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending bulk transfer. Retrying...
 Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending bulk transfer.ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending bulk transfer. Retrying...
 Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending bulk transfer.ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending bulk transfer. Retrying...
 Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending bulk transfer.ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst sending bulk transfer.

ERROR: Failed to send handshake!ERROR: Failed to send handshake!ERROR: Failed to receive handshake response. Result: -7
ERROR: Failed to receive handshake response. Result: -7
ERROR: Protocol initialisation failed!

ERROR: Protocol initialisation failed!

Releasing device interface...
```

I've tried both with and without superuser context (`sudo`) and the result is always the same. I am also unable to retrieve the PIT file from the phone.

However, the boot loader is successfully unlocked as I can see in the freshly initialized (due to the data wipe) Android, while running, and also during boot (shows a warning regarding the unlocked state, which has to be dismissed before the boot continues).

I am successful in entering ODIN/download mode (holding both <kbd>Volume</kbd> keys *while* the phone restarts, followed by <kbd>Volume+</kbd>), but still nothing seems to work when attempting to communicate with the phone.

I also tried using JOdin3, which detects the device and all, but already fails to retrieve the PIT file as well. I suppose it must be using Heimdall under the hood (?) ...

What part am I missing? Has the procedure somehow changed for newer Samsung phone models?

---

NB: in order to get fastboot mode to work (which I had tried before), I had to disconnect a Yubikey that I was using on the system. After that `fastboot devices` properly showed the phone, but using `fastboot flash ...` was equally unsuccessful (I tried `fastboot flash boot <file>` and `fastboot flash boot_a <file>` to no avail). Prior to unplugging it (although connected to a different root hub), it failed to detect the phone in fastboot mode.

Comment: how about Magisk [Installation Instructions](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#instructions)

Comment: @alecxs could you point me to the part you specifically mean? [I read it, yes](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#samsung-system-as-root), but as I tried to point out in my question any attempts with `fastboot` failed. Which was when I found out Samsung uses a proprietary mode and proprietary tool called ODIN of which Heimdall is an open-source counterpart.

Comment: patch the whole AP_\*.tar.md5 file, flash from Odin together with BL, CP, and CSC

Comment: @alecxs Right, you realize that ODIN runs on _Windows_, though? Which is why I was using Heimdall in the first place. I'm on Ubuntu (also noted in the question).

Comment: if heimdall issue is with reading pit only, you can get pit from stock firmware too. you can get partition+file names from pit with hex editor [manually](https://superuser.com/q/1561912) or with [PIT Magic](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1916936), [PIT Viewer](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2953072). if flashing succeed but you get *"Only official released binaries are allowed to be flashed"* check KG/ [RMM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3747535) state

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, @alecxs! Much appreciated. Yep, it seems like I have to set up a Windows in a VM or on a laptop and try ODIN instead.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4188991

Comment: from github issue #414: 1) make sure it's not usage problem with `--no-reboot` `--resume` flags 2) add *50-android.rules* to */etc/udev/rules.d* 3) compile [libusb](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb/files) from source + recompile heimdall

Comment: from github issue #482: try this [prebuilt](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=4349826312261708650) heimdall

Comment: @alecxs it's not the `--no-reboot` `--resume` issue, but I'll try the other advice. Failing that I may have to install a Windows and use ODIN. I don't quite dare running ODIN inside Wine 